# Selenium - unable to load extension in Edge build 17763

Tags: javascript, selenium, microsoft-edge

I recently updated windows to have latest Edge and now I am not able to load extension.

Here is how I am trying to load it:

```
const edgeExtensionDir = [process.env.LOCALAPPDATA + '\\Packages\\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\LocalState\\Extension'];
const edge = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');
let service = new edge.ServiceBuilder().setPort(55555).build();
let edgeOptions = new edge.Options();
edgeOptions.set("extensionPaths", edgeExtensionDir);
let driver = edge.Driver.createSession(edgeOptions, service);
```

Before update this code was working as expected, now it just opens Edge and automation works but extension is not loaded.

Comment: Did you got any error message or warning? If yes, Please try to inform us about that may help to narrow down the issue. For testing purpose, can you try to make a test on other machine which have previous update? It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I forgot to mention, it threw no errors in console and no error was displayed in edge as well, I tried to set extension path to invalid path and again no errors. It is working on another machine which uses edge build 17134 but I need to test the latest one.

Comment: For testing purpose, Can you remove the latest update and move back to previous update to check whether it solves the issue or not? It can help us to make sure that new update has some issue. I try to find but I did not get any information about this issue with the latest updates.

Comment: Sure I can try to restore last version later today.

Comment: Let us know the testing result after you restore to previous version. We will try to provide further suggestions, If needed.

Comment: Hi, sorry for very late reply, I had no time to investigate this issue further, now I reinstalled windows so I have older build and it works there, now I have edge 17134. I have another pc available with the latest windows build and there I am still not able to load extensions.